# jQuery only affects the last result in a while loop: MySQL

Tags: jquery, mysql, while-loop

I am trying to make the background color change for each checked item in a row in a while loop. Currently the jQuery only works on the last row. I did put an `$i` variable in the input id, but to be honest, I'm not sure what to do beyond it. I tried [this](http://eligeske.com/jquery/while-loop-with-jquery/), the `.each` function, and a bunch of answers on Stack Overflow, but I can't figure out how to take care of this.

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#org[$i]').change(function(){
        if(this.checked){
            $(this).siblings('table').removeClass('unchecked');
            $(this).siblings('table').addClass('checked');
            $(this).parentsUntil('td').removeClass('unchecked');
            $(this).parentsUntil('td').addClass('checked');
        } else {
            $(this).siblings('table').removeClass('checked');
            $(this).siblings('table').addClass('unchecked');
            $(this).parentsUntil('td').removeClass('checked');
            $(this).parentsUntil('td').addClass('unchecked');
        }               
    });
});
```

Here is the loop (with some unimportant stuff cut out). `$i` iterates properly in each `#org` (I checked in Firebug):

```
if ($i % 4 == 0) echo ($i > 0? '</tr>' : '') . '<tr>';

echo "<td class=\"unchecked\">
    <div class=\"unchecked\">
        <input id=\"org[".$i."]\" style=\"float:right\" type=\"checkbox\" name=\"org\" value=\"".$row['i_id']."\"/>
        <table class=\"unchecked\">
            //blah, blah, blah
        </table>
    </div>
</td>';                 

if ($i == $countRows - 1)
    echo '</tr>';
$i++;
```

Comment: Why do you use `#org[$i]` in the javascript ? instead of `#org[0]`, `#org[1]`, `#org[2]`,...

Comment: The number of items in the array changes all the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to match an id like `org[1]` as output by PHP, but you're using a jQuery selector with `[$i]` in it - that doesn't work, for a few reasons.

What will work is a jQuery selector like this:

```
$('input[id^="org\["]')
```

This will select input elements with an `id` that starts with `org[`.  I placed a backspace in front of the bracket because jQuery has a special meaning for brackets, and this "escapes" that special meaning.

Comment: I almost understand that. Would you please show me how to do it in the code? Do I need to create a special function for this?

Comment: You're welcome, and good on ya for figuring it out yourself.  I often find lessons you figure out own your own stick the best.  Take a good look at @Justin Wood's answer below - His upvote came from me.  That's a very clever and easy way to accomplish this without any scripting.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use CSS for this?

```
input[type="checkbox"] + label {
    // Whatever you want to do
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
    // Whatever you want to do.
}
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/MLfs3/) is a simple fiddle showing this off.

Comment: I tried that and this (if it works) should take care of everything

Comment: I usually find shifting work from JS to CSS to be good thing.  This is a clever solution.  +1

Answer (score 0):

In you javascript you use $i but it is pp variable. Actually you can use class not ids for this purpose

```
<?php foreach($items as $item){ echo '<input type="checkbox" ..something else... class="dummy" />';}
```

In javascript

```
$('.dummy').change(function(e){ //Do something that you need});
```

Comment: I'm better at jquery (which isn't saying much). I don't know what to do with your information. Sorry.

Comment: jQuery is javascript. You add ID to your inputs but you can add class to them if they do similar things like i wrote on example class='class_name' and use it in jquery to react on all inputs with this class and not write code for each id. Line with javascript in example above use class in jquery toreact on all changes in elements with class dummy.