# check all checkboxes AND change color of all Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, css

I have been trying to figure this out for hours, switching it around every which way, but nothing seems to work. Each function works great individually, but I can't seem to get the .change function to fire when the check all button is clicked. What am I doing wrong?

The first function is from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480984/adding-a-select-all-checkbox#_=_): It selects all the checkboxes, but the change does not affect the second function.
The second function is from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18793532/jquery-only-affects-the-last-result-in-a-while-loop-mysql-php/18793693#18793693): It changes the class of the divs (and therefore the css), but only if a single checkbox is checked/unchecked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
(function() {
    var checked = false;
    $('button.check-all').click(function() {
        checked = !checked;
        $('input[class^="orgImgColl\["]').prop('checked', checked); 
        if (checked) $(this).text('Uncheck All');
        else $(this).text('Check All');
    });
})();

 $('input[class^="orgImgColl\["]').change(function(){
    if(this.checked){
        $(this).children('table').removeClass('unchecked');
        $(this).children('table').addClass('checked');
        $(this).siblings('table').removeClass('unchecked');
        $(this).siblings('table').addClass('checked');
        $(this).parentsUntil('tr').removeClass('unchecked');
        $(this).parentsUntil('tr').addClass('checked');
   } else {
       $(this).children('table').removeClass('checked');
        $(this).children('table').addClass('unchecked');
        $(this).siblings('table').removeClass('checked');
        $(this).siblings('table').addClass('unchecked');
        $(this).parentsUntil('tr').removeClass('checked');
        $(this).parentsUntil('tr').addClass('unchecked');   
    }

});
```

});

here is the HTML/PHP

```
<div class=\"unchecked\">";

echo "<input class=\"orgImgColl[".$i."]\" style=\"float:right\" type=\"checkbox\" name=\"orgImgColl[]\" value=\"".$row['img_id']."\"/>

<table class="unchecked" id="imgList" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" width="90%">
etc.
```

Just so you know the $i in the input class is for debugging purposes, so you can ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because when you change the checked state using script the change event is not fired, the solution is to trigger the change event manually once the checked property is changed using `.change()` or `.trigger('change')`

```
(function () {
    var checked = false;
    $('button.check-all').click(function () {
        checked = !checked;
        $('input[class^="orgImgColl\["]').prop('checked', checked).change();
        if (checked) {
            $(this).text('Uncheck All');
        } else {
            $(this).text('Check All');
        }
    });
})();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Re49j/)

You can improve the selector by changing only those checkboxes which are not in the desired state using something like (not tested)

```
$('input[class^="orgImgColl\["]')[checked?'not':'filter'](':checked').prop('checked', checked).change();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bPYkK/)

Comment: OMG I love you! Thanks! I'll hit the accepted answer thing as soon as it allows me